# Deploy reactjs by electron for creating desktop app

Tags: reactjs, electron

I know my question is obvious but I want to find best practice for that. How can we deploy a reactjs project by electron in lowest size of package? Can we deploy the built reactjs project by electron? I use `create-react-app` and I don't want to eject that.

Comment: Obvious answer: https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate

Comment: I don’t want to use webpack. I use create-react-app

Comment: I don't know React, but You can create your app as you want and use electron like a web-server and browser. Just take `dist` folder and pack with electron.